# iOS build crashes after upgrading to ReactNative 0.72.10 and react-native-reanimated 3.6.1

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-reanimated

We have been using react-native-reanimated 3.6.1 with ReactNative 0.71.15 but after upgrading to ReactNative 0.72.10 the iOS build crashes with the following message:

```
▸ Compiling WorkletRuntimeDecorator.cpp

❌  /Users/me/work/mobile-app/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/Common/cpp/SharedItems/Shareables.h:243:13: 'this' argument to member function 'data' has type 'const jsi::ArrayBuffer', but function is not marked const

            arrayBuffer.data(rt),
^



❌  /Users/me/work/mobile-app/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/Common/cpp/SharedItems/Shareables.h:244:13: 'this' argument to member function 'data' has type 'const jsi::ArrayBuffer', but function is not marked const

            arrayBuffer.data(rt) + arrayBuffer.size(rt)) {
           ^


▸ Compiling WorkletRuntime.cpp

❌  /Users/lucian/work/mobile-app/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/Common/cpp/SharedItems/Shareables.h:243:13: 'this' argument to member function 'data' has type 'const jsi::ArrayBuffer', but function is not marked const

            arrayBuffer.data(rt),
           ^



❌  /Users/me/work/mobile-app/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/Common/cpp/SharedItems/Shareables.h:244:13: 'this' argument to member function 'data' has type 'const jsi::ArrayBuffer', but function is not marked const

            arrayBuffer.data(rt) + arrayBuffer.size(rt)) {
           ^


▸ Compiling WorkletEventHandler.cpp

❌  /Users/me/work/mobile-app/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/Common/cpp/SharedItems/Shareables.h:243:13: 'this' argument to member function 'data' has type 'const jsi::ArrayBuffer', but function is not marked const

            arrayBuffer.data(rt),
           ^
```

Any ideea on what could be wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a workaround to get my app to build, when running into this error, by patching react-native-reanimated using patch-package.

In the file /node_modules/react-native-reanimated/Common/cpp/SharedItems/Shareables.h, change line 227 from:

```
const jsi::ArrayBuffer &arrayBuffer
```

to

```
jsi::ArrayBuffer arrayBuffer
```

There is probably a more "correct" way to fix this, but it works for me in the meantime!

Comment: We've moved to 3.7.2 which fixes this issue :)